# I don't know what to write on the time intervals of the VHDL testbench

Tags: vhdl, rom, alu

I am writing two VHDL codes; one for an ALU and another one for a two-port data memory.

After some useful recommendations from contibutors here in Stack Overflow, I have managed to come up with the following VHDL codes for an ALU and a two-port data memory.

The problem is, I don't know what to put on the memory's testbench to actually make all the addresses show up in the simulation, and as for the ALU code, I am not sure that simulation result is the correct one.

The purpose of the testbench for the ALU is to show all the operations dictated in the VHDL code, are showing up on the simulation, and the purpose of the testbench for the memory is to test if all the address values implemented on VHDL code are showing up on the simulation. Can someone please help as this is really important for me to finish it. Many thanks in advance to whoever decides to help. I have just started learning VHDL so sorry if the mistakes are too many.

Here is the VHDL code for the ALU:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity alu is
    port (
    A, B: in signed (31 downto 0);
            opcode: in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
            Result: out signed (31 downto 0));            
end entity alu;

architecture dataoperations of alu is
begin 
process (A, B, opcode)
begin
    Result <= A + B when opcode="001010" -- Addition
    else    A - B when opcode="001000" --Subtraction
    else    abs(A) when opcode="001011" --Absolute value of A
    else    -A  when opcode="001101" --Minus A
    else    abs(B) when opcode="000001" -- Absolute value of B
    else    -B when opcode="001001" --Minus B
    else    A or B when opcode="000110" --A or B
    else    not A when opcode="001111" --Not A 
    else    not B when opcode="000101" --Not B
    else    A and B when opcode="001100" -- A and B
    else    A xor B when opcode="000010"; --A exclusive or B

end process;

end architecture dataoperations;
```

Here is the testbench for the ALU:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity alu_test is
end entity alu_test;

architecture test of alu_test is

-- Introducing the Unit Under Test (UUT), in this case, the ALU

component alu
port ( A, B: in signed (31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
            opcode: in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := (others => '0');
            Result: out signed (31 downto 0));
end component;            
    
    -- Input generator
    signal A, B: signed (31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal opcode: std_logic_vector (5 downto 0) := (others => '0') ;
    -- Output display
    signal Result: signed (31 downto 0);
    
begin
    
    uut:alu
        port map ( A => A, B => B, opcode => opcode, Result => Result );
   
    stimulus_process: process 
    begin
    
    wait for 5 ns;
    
    
    A <= "00000000000000000000000000001001";
    B <= "00000000000000000000000000001111";
    
    opcode <= "001010";
    wait for 5 ns;
    opcode <= "001000";
    wait for 5 ns;
    opcode <= "001011";
    wait for 5 ns;
    opcode <= "001101";
    wait for 5 ns;
    opcode <= "000001";
    wait for 5 ns;
    opcode <= "001001";
    wait for 5 ns;
    opcode <= "000110";
    wait for 5 ns;
    opcode <= "001111";
    wait for 5 ns;
    opcode <= "000101";
    wait for 5 ns;
    opcode <= "001100";
    wait for 5 ns;
    opcode <= "000010";
    end process;
   
end;
```

The VHDL code for the data memory:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all; 
entity rom is
    port ( addr1, addr2: in unsigned (4 downto 0);
      data_out1, data_out2: out unsigned (31 downto 0));
end entity rom;

architecture dataflow of rom is
    type rom_array is array (0 to 31) 
                    of std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    signal rom_data: rom_array := 
                    (x"00000000", x"00000000", x"000005E4", x"0000EE7C", x"000175FE", x"00000BAE", x"0000E4E0", x"00000F20", x"00013CE3", x"000072B0", x"000075BE", x"00005974", x"0000DC71", x"00009064", x"0000D246", x"00017CE1", x"00015275", x"00011CD8",x"000131F3", x"00013B3F", x"00000149", x"000124D5",                    x"000051CD", x"00015A16", x"00016EAE", x"0000A312", x"00007F96", x"000161A4", x"0001673C", x"00005E6F", x"000154B5", x"00000000");


end architecture dataflow;
```

And the testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity rom_test is
end entity rom_test;

architecture behaviour of rom_test is

-- Introducing the UUT, here it is rom

component rom
port ( addr1, addr2: in unsigned (4 downto 0);
      data_out1, data_out2: out unsigned (31 downto 0));
end component;

    signal addr1, addr2: unsigned (4 downto 0);
    signal data_out1, data_out2: unsigned (31 downto 0);
    
begin

    uut: rom
        port map ( addr1 => addr1, addr2 => addr2, data_out1 => data_out1, data_out2 => data_out2 );
```

Additionally, it is a 32-bit ALU with 6-bit opcode, and it is a two-port data memory with 5-bit input (on each port) and 32-bit output.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: * I don't know what to put on the memory's testbench to actually make all the addresses show up in the simulation*  All the addresses are the index range of type rom_array, (0 to 31). To traverse those you can use a loop statement or increment or decrement a value from one bound to the other (process statements loop). *the ALU code, I am not sure that simulation result is the correct one* What would make you sure? Compare against that.

Comment: How would I use the loop, I am sorry but I have never done this before

Comment: I was unable to find the lecture and reference materials for your course (ENG7158?) to determine whether you missed some implied study or exposure to reference materials but you appear not to have extended your knowledge of VHDL beyond lecture slides. Without seeing the actual assignment the question arises whether those were adequate preparation. Like the for loop in process STIMULUS [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePA5E.jpg). extending the range of i to 0 to 31 for example.

Comment: I have edited my post with the information about the alu and rom